# How to reverse the sentence using streams in java

Tags: java, string, java-stream, reverse

i would like to reverse the sentence using streams api in java

eg: input --> Hi hello stack over flow

output --> flow over stack hello Hi

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the string *keeping the delimiters*
2. Collect the chunks using custom collector with the `StringBuilder::insert` method, or simpler `Stream::reduce`:

```java
String str = "Hi hello stack over flow";

System.out.println("'" + 
    Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)"))
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, s) -> sb.insert(0, s), StringBuilder::append)
    .toString()
    + "'"
);

System.out.println("'" + 
    Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)"))
          .reduce("", (acc, s) -> s + acc)
    + "'"
);
```

Output:

```
'flow over stack hello Hi'
'flow over stack hello Hi'
```

Comment: Seems like you're solving someone's homework problem. A problem with no work shown by the OP.

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee with order of the stream of Strings with this code.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, how come?  `Arrays.stream` provides **sequential stream**, `StringBuilder::insert(0, x)` provides reversed order,

Comment: Well ok then ...

Comment: can you please explain it . how it is working

Comment: I think I provided the description.  What exactly is not clear to you in the code snippets?